# How to draw separate plots for two instances in Prometheus?

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus

I have two instances running a job and sending gauge metrics to pushgateway.

For some reason Prometheus draws one plot for one job and two different instances. Here are the plots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The question is what am I doing wrong and how to make Prometheus to draw separate continuous plots for these instances?

I'm using python's [prometheus_client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python).

Answer (score 0):

In Prometheus, a metric is identified by the name of the metric **AND**  the set of labeled dimensions. Each time your `instance` label changes, it is another metric and thus another graph.

In order to merge the metric, you have to compute a resulting metric without the label that changes. Average is often a good candidate but doesn't matter if the metrics don't overlap:

```
avg(perf_test_concurrency) without(instance)
```